# PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/user/Android/sdk]! -- UBUNTU

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, dart, flutter

After installing flutter, I installed Android SDK on my ubuntu machine and keep getting this error when I try to run the emulator.

```
./emulator -avd khophi
```

This is my current system's path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=~/.flutterSetup/flutter/bin:$PATH
# -------
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/sdk:$PATH
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/user/Android/sdk:$PATH
export PATH=/home/user/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/user/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/user/Android/build-tools:$PATH
```

And also get this error when I run flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Linux, locale en_NG)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
    28.0.2)
✗ Android SDK file not found: /home/user/Android/sdk/build- 
    tools/28.0.2/aapt.
[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
```

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

But I can only see version 26.0.3 and 27.0.3 in "build-tools". Please help.

Comment: Is your username actually `user`?

Comment: Haha. Nope. That was edited.

Comment: Which Android SDK did you install? You also need to install API 28. The easiest way to do this would be to just install Android Studio and let it download what's needed.

Comment: Thanks. I previously did that. The install process was slow and seemed heavy. Would like to use VScode instead.

Comment: Well it looks like Flutter depends on Android Studio, just looking at that code. You need to install API 28 manually if you want to avoid Android Studio: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102955/how-to-install-sdk-packages-offline-after-download-is-complete